# How do I post comments under posts in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a method, who add comment's to database. For each posts, own comment. My blade page with form have a hidden input, from witch i take id post

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $post->post_id }}" name="post_id">
```

My method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Music_comment();
    $comment->comment = $request->comment;
    $comment->author_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = (int)$request->input('post_id');

    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Комментарий добавлен');    
}
```

But I can’t get the comments under the post, it’s necessary that under each post, a defined comment is displayed that corresponds to the post id. My view composer method:

```
View::composer('*', function($music) {
        $music->with(['post_comment' => Music_comment::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)->get()]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you should show model relationship on `Music_comment` Model and also on `Post` It would be nice. Assume that you have correctly defined relationships you can do it like this.

```
View::composer('*', function($music) {
        $music->with(['post.comment' => function($query){
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4);
        };
    });
```

Hope this helps.

**P.S.**

If you want to retrieve Authenticated user's id You can do like this `Auth::id()`

Answer (score 0):

simply you can handle it with laravel eloquent relationships. 
**1) Add this function on your Music model.**

```
public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'id', 'post_id');
       //here id is parent id, post_id is child id which is in comments table
    }
```

**2) access all your comment using this code on laravel blade / on your controller *function directly**

```
 $comments =  $music->comments();
```

Or,

```
$comments =  $music->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)->get()
```

[for one-to-many relationship guide click this link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)